# Angular 2 pass formgroup to router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a main component and several children each representing a step in a process where the user has to enter data into a form.

In the main component I have a *router-outlet*. I would like to use reactive forms for this and I wonder how I can have one formgroup in the main component and let all the children access it when the user routes to the next process step.

I tried doing this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <router-outlet [group]="myFormGroup"></router-outlet>
</form>
```

But this throws an error as the router-outlet is not build to have custom attributes.

Would I use a shared service for this? Where would my `<form>` tag go?

**UPDATE**

I just discovered that I can do something like this:

**parentComponent:**

```
export class ProcessStepsComponent implements OnInit {
   myFormGroup: FormGroup;
   constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder
   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   });
}
```

**childComponent:**

```
export class ChainingAddressComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private processSteps:ProcessStepsComponent) { 
      console.log(processSteps.myFormGroup);//returns the FormGroup
   }

   ngOnInit() {

   }

}
```

I can inject the parent into my child in the constructor and use its formgroup.

Is there any downside on using this?

Comment: Can you represent each step as an individual form instead of placing the router component inside the form tag? One down side I see is using a component to hold state.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't represent it as individual steps. I see no advantage in putting the Formgroup into a service.